# Model containing a list of other model in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, one-to-many

This question may seem trivial but I've really been pulling my hair off for the last few days over this.
I am trying to create a One-To-Many relationship using Entity Framework.
I have two models. The first model is Team:

```
public class Team
{
   public int TeamId {get;set;}
   public string TeamName {get;set;}
   public string SportType {get;set;}
   public List<Player> Players {get;set;}
}
```

As you can see, I want my team to contain a list of players. My player class is defined like that:

```
public class Player
{
   public int PlayerId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
   public double Salary {get;set;}
   public string Gender {get;set;}

   [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
   public Team Team {get;set;}
}
```

And that is my dbcontext class:

```
public class TeamDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Team> Teams {get;set;}
   public DbSet<Player> Players {get;set;}

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelCreator modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasRequired<Team>(p => p.Team).WithMany(t => t.Players).HasForeignKey(p => p.TeamId);
   }

   public TeamDbContext() : base("TeamDb")
   {
   }
}
```

This is my main:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{    
   TeamDbContext db = new TeamDbContext();

   // Create a new Player    
   Player Ben = new Player() {Name = "Ben", Age = 10};                
   db.Players.Add(Ben);   
   db.SaveChanges();

   // Create a new Team    
   Team LosVegasTeam = new Team() {TeamName = "LosVegas", SportType = "Soccer"};    
   LosVegasTeam.Players = new List<Player> {Ben};
   db.Teams.Add(LosVegasTeam);    
   db.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

There must be a mistake somewhere (maybe even in the main itself) since even though when the application is running everything seem to work, the second time I am running the application I am able to retrieve everything from the database excepts the Team's players list (it is basically null).

I would appreciate any help, I am really hopeless.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make complex type properties `virtual` to enable **lazy loading**.

```
public class Team
{
   public int TeamId {get;set;}
   public string TeamName {get;set;}
   public string SportType {get;set;}
   public virtual List<Player> Players {get;set;}
}

public class Player
{
   public int PlayerId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
   public double Salary {get;set;}
   public string Gender {get;set;}

   [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
   public virtual Team Team {get;set;}
}
```